# Allow Stack Overflow profile rather than Careers profile to be shown for "Who you will work with"

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-bydesign, jobs

On Careers, there is a section for "Who you'll work with". Currently, when you invite your fellow co-workers, it forces them to use their Careers profile (in addition, their resumes) directly on your company page (the page you are trying to get people to look at so you hire great talent!) But it's a bit misleading when outsiders are looking at "Who you'll work with" if those same people's links are simply to what I would call more of a resume looking for potential other jobs.

Please allow the links to connect to the Stack Overflow profile rather than the Careers profile.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a good idea, but has its drawbacks. While some would want their Stack Overflow profiles to be shown to impress, others may want Super User, Code Review, Pro Webmasters, or some other Stack Exchange site profile to be shown. If anything, users should be allowed to select which profile they want shown in relation the company.

Comment: exactly, my point was when you invite someone via the careers site it sends an email.  when that co worker clicks the email they should be given an option to select what to link to careers, my so profile or even my global stackexchange profile.  to me its strange for an outsider seeing your team is looking for other work.

Comment: Just because you have a Careers profile doesn't mean that you are looking for work. Granted, our primary audience are developers looking for better jobs, but you can set your profile options to reflect that you're not looking. Plus, you can link your profile from many of our other sites to your Careers profile.

Answer (score 9):

### On (not) being misleading

> But its a bit misleading when outsiders are looking at "Who youll work with" if those same people's links are simply to what I would call more of a resume looking for potential other jobs.

What's misleading about that? If I look at your job posting and it says the people I'll be working with are all people actively looking to work elsewhere, that's *very* informative about your company and not *remotely* misleading for me.

That said, I don't know what you'd call "more of a resume looking for potential other jobs." I hope you don't mean just having a SO Careers page in general.

I am *quite* content in my current job and expect to remain with my employer for quite a while, but I'll still keep a well-maintained LinkedIn profile - and I need to get my SO Careers profile up to date, I've just noticed. That's a matter of establishing and maintaining my professional identity and personal brand, though, and not a matter of me looking for a new job.

### On the importance of seeing the potential coworkers' Career pages

This being their *professional profile*, it details their expertise, experience, position in the company, and so on. As a potential employee at your company, that's the kind of thing I'd want to see: their professional identity, and their identity within your company.

Their profile on Stack Overflow won't tell me many of those things, though their activity might tell me a little. It's not a high priority, and if your employees feel like their Stack Overflow profile is worth showing off, they have the opportunity to link to their account in their profile.

**I would prefer the *Who you will work with* section to link to Careers profiles.**

Especially because for any other network site profile they'd rather show off, that can be linked to in their professional profile.

Comment: I agree with this. My SO profile is a mish-mash of a lot of things most people (especially those who aren't regular SO users) either wouldn't care about or wouldn't know what to do with. Whereas my Careers profile is tailored to a professional job-hunting/job-offering type of environment and allows me to showcase the more relevant aspects of my SO (and network) participation.

Comment: No need for another answer.  This is essentially our stance right now.